# How do I only get future and today dates instead of future and past dates?

Tags: reactjs, json, momentjs

This `JSON` shows past, today, and future date. Using `momentjs`
I would like to receive only today and future date properties.

```
   {
    2022-05-01:
    11891: {error: false, price: 15, original_price: 120, suggested_price: 15, suggested_price_without_restriction: 81, …}
    12157: {error: false, price: 7, original_price: 150, suggested_price: 7, suggested_price_without_restriction: 36, …}
    property: {expectedroomssold_adjusted: 6.34, exproomssold_l1: 3.82, exproomssold_u1: 8.86, exproomssold_l2: 1.3, exproomssold_u2: 11.38, …}
    [[Prototype]]: Object
    2022-05-02:
    11891: {error: false, price: 15, original_price: 120, suggested_price: 15, suggested_price_without_restriction: 87, …}
    12157: {error: false, price: 7, original_price: 155, suggested_price: 7, suggested_price_without_restriction: 39, …}
    property: {expectedroomssold_adjusted: 6.57, exproomssold_l1: 4, exproomssold_u1: 9.13, exproomssold_l2: 1.44, exproomssold_u2: 11.69, …}
    [[Prototype]]: Object
    2022-05-03:
    11891: {error: false, price: 15, original_price: 120, suggested_price: 15, suggested_price_without_restriction: 91, …}
    12157: {error: false, price: 7, original_price: 155, suggested_price: 7, suggested_price_without_restriction: 41, …}
    property: {expectedroomssold_adjusted: 6.3, exproomssold_l1: 3.79, exproomssold_u1: 8.81, exproomssold_l2: 1.28, exproomssold_u2: 11.32, …}
    [[Prototype]]: Object
    2022-05-04:
    11891: {error: false, price: 15, original_price: 120, suggested_price: 15, suggested_price_without_restriction: 95, …}
    12157: {error: false, price: 7, original_price: 155, suggested_price: 7, suggested_price_without_restriction: 43, …}
    property: {expectedroomssold_adjusted: 6.07, exproomssold_l1: 3.61, exproomssold_u1: 8.53, exproomssold_l2: 1.14, exproomssold_u2: 11, …}
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I have understood your JSON structure but with minimal JSON data I have tried this using momentjs.
I have used diff method of momentjs to check future, past or today's date.

https://jsbin.com/casogaxubu/edit?html,js,console,output

```
let arr = [];
Object.keys(data).forEach(function (keyD) {   
  if (moment().diff(keyD, "days") <= 0) {
    var objs = {};
    objs[keyD] = data[keyD];
    arr.push(objs);
  }
});
console.log("arr:", arr);`
```

Can you check if this helps?